# Generating colon seperated path list using find

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script

I am trying to generate some PATH-like directory list, using simple bash- and UNIX commands. I think this one here gives me the output I like to use:

```
$ find /usr/local -type d -exec dirname \{\} \; | sort -u | tr '\n' ':'
/usr:/usr/local:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/python2.6:/usr/local/lib/site_ruby:/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8:/usr/local/lib/xemacs:/usr/local/share:/usr/local/share/emacs:/usr/local/share/emacs/23.2:/usr/local/share/sgml:/usr/local/share/xml:/usr/local/share/zsh:
```

However, when I try to use this expression using command substitution (e.g. for assigning to a variable), it breaks:

```
$ echo $(find /usr/local -type d -exec dirname \{\} \; | sort -u | tr '\n' ':' )
/usr /usr/local /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/python2.6 /usr/local/lib/site_ruby /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8 /usr/local/lib/xemacs /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/emacs /usr/local/share/emacs/23.2 /usr/local/share/sgml /usr/local/share/xml /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or how I can achieve my goal differently?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, neither in bash nor zsh. Both produce the same output for me.

Comment: Hm, I am using Bash 4.1.5 on Debian Squeeze. Maybe there's some shopt which triggers this?

Comment: I'm on 4.2.24 with Ubuntu. Have you set any custom options in one of your startup scripts?

Comment: Funny enough this happens for me only in interactive shells. When I put this in a script, it works :-/

Comment: Interesting. Found any differences in your `bashrc` or `bash_profile` that could influence the behavior?

Comment: No, not so far. There are a few shopt calls, but none that trigger this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of the environment variable `IFS`, the field separator. It is not used in the `find` form, but in the `echo $(find)` form.

```
export IFS="-"
echo $(...)
```

compare:

```
export IFS=:
echo $(echo asdf:asdf:asdf)
> asdf asdf asdf

export IFS=;
echo $(echo asdf:asdf:asdf)
> asdf:asdf:asdf

export IFS=:
unset IFS
echo $(echo asdf:asdf:asdf)
> asdf:asdf:asdf
```